# How to get distinct values for multiselect parameter in SSRS report - databricks

Tags: sql, reporting-services, databricks, multi-select

In my report there is a multiselect parameter Warehouse and there is another multiselect parameter Supplier.

I need to populate Supplier parameter based on selected Warehouses.

This is the query I'm using,

```
SELECT SupplierCode,SupplierName,WarehouseCode 
FROM SupplierIntegrated_data 
WHERE CreatedDate >= ? AND CreatedDate <= ?
GROUP BY SupplierCode,
         SupplierName,
         WarehouseCode
ORDER BY SupplierCode ASC
```

I have to return WarehouseCode as a field because I have to filter dataset from warehouse list.
From that it returns duplicated values for SupplierCode.

Is there any method to remove duplicates from a parameter values from the report end?

Comment: Please can you add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: Also can you tag the DBMS

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT to remove duplicate value from the GROUP BY clause

```
select DISTINCT SupplierCode from (
SELECT SupplierCode,SupplierName,WarehouseCode 
FROM SupplierIntegrated_data 
WHERE CreatedDate >= ? AND CreatedDate <= ?
GROUP BY SupplierCode,
         SupplierName,
         WarehouseCode
 ORDER BY SupplierCode ASC 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer maybe not be exactly correct as I have no experience with DataBricks or it's version of SQL but that aside, this is how you would normally do things.

1:- Create a Dataset containing a list of warehouses `ds_WH`

```
SELECT DISTINCT WarehouseCode 
FROM SupplierIntegrated_data 
WHERE CreatedDate >= ? AND CreatedDate <= ? 
ORDER BY WarehouseCode
```

2:- Create a parameter for warehouses (`pWH`), Set to multi-value and set available values to query (`ds_WH` from above in this example)

3:- Create a Dataset containing a list of Supplier for selected Warehouse(s) `dsSup`

```
SELECT DISTINCT SupplierCode,SupplierName
FROM SupplierIntegrated_data 
WHERE CreatedDate >= ? AND CreatedDate <= ? 
   AND WarehouseCode IN(?) -- syntax here might be wrong?
GROUP BY SupplierCode,
         SupplierName,
ORDER BY SupplierCode ASC
```

4:- Create a parameter for Suppliers (`pSup`), set to multi-value and set avilable values to query (`dsSup` from above in this example)

5:- Create a daset for the main report data `dsMain`

```
SELECT *
FROM myMainDataTablew
WHERE CreatedDate >= ? AND CreatedDate <= ?
       AND WarehouseCode IN(?) -- syntax here might be wrong?
       AND SupplierCode IN(?) -- syntax here might be wrong?
```

As I said, not sure what the syntax should be, if this was written using MS SQL Server as the data source then it would be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM myMainDataTablew
WHERE CreatedDate >= @StartDate AND CreatedDate <= @EndDate
       AND WarehouseCode IN(@pWH) -- syntax here might be wrong?
       AND SupplierCode IN(@pSup) -- syntax here might be wrong?
```